# Find the center index of first occurrence sequence in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, ecmascript-6

I want to find the center point(index) of first appear sequence by given 
a multiple strings in a **large array**

for example:

```js
var array = ["c6dafc", "c6dafc", "1d2129", "1d2129", "1d2129", "cfcfff", "cfcfff", "ffffff", "1d2129", "1d2129", "1d2129", "1d2129"]
```

function call: (try to find the center index based on `1d2129`, if not found then search `32cd32`

```js
var result = somefunction(["1d2129", "32cd32"]);
```

In the above example the result should return `3` since the first occurrence sequence of `1d2129` is at `2` and the last is `4` not `11`. If `1d2129` didn't appear then should search for `32cd32`.

noted: if the occurred number is an odd number should return center index, if an even number should return `centerPoint - 1`

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: you try it yourself:P

Comment: I tried, but the performance are not very ideal.

Comment: What is `function somefunction(...array) {...` made of?  Cottage cheese? Or actual living breathing JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Loop over list of search words

2) For each word, find out first occurrence. If occurrence is there then find out last one in the sequence. 

3) Find out the center occurrence from the first and last indexes.

4) if no occurrence found, then move to next search word.

```js
const somefunction = (data, arr) => {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    const search = arr[i];
    const first_index = data.findIndex(item => item === search);
    if (first_index > -1) {
      let last_index = first_index;
      while (data[last_index + 1] === search) {
        last_index++;
      }
      return Math.floor((first_index + last_index) / 2);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return -1; // not found at all
};

var array = [
  "c6dafc",
  "c6dafc",
  "1d2129",
  "1d2129",
  "1d2129",
  "cfcfff",
  "cfcfff",
  "ffffff",
  "1d2129",
  "1d2129",
  "1d2129",
  "1d2129"
];

var result = somefunction(array, ["1d2129", "32cd32"]);

console.log(result);
```